# How to test dynamically defined methods that are based on other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a model called `DeviceState` which contains states like "active","offline","online".

I have another model called `Device` which `belongs_to` to `DeviceState`.

To have methods such as `@device.active?` and `@device.offline?` on the device model, I've defined a dynamic method like so:

```
  DeviceState.all.each do |method|
    define_method((method.name + "?").to_sym) do
        self.device_state.name == method.name
    end
  end
```

My problem is that when I try to create tests on the `Device` model, the dynamic method are not created because the `DeviceState` model hasn't been populated on the database while the test environment started up. So by the time I create the `DeviceState` data with factory girl, it would be too late.

One solution I tried is to seed the `DeviceState` in `spec_helper`, however while this worked for the first test it didn't work for all the rest as the database cleaner removed the data.

What would be the best way to overcome those dynamically defined methods?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't define these methods dynamically. This is a huge code smell.

Comment: Really? But then every time I will need to add a new state I'll have to add new methods to the Device model. Now I simply add it to the DeviceState model and everything works. This was the idea behind it. No good?

Comment: The model `Device` is loaded when your server starts and do not reloaded again (I mean in PRODUCTION) and you will not get a new defined method when a new state will be added. Please be careful with it. Start your App in Production mode and test it!

Comment: This sort of chicanery is usually done with `method_missing` and, if you're smart, a `respond_to?` override. That said, just how often are you expecting to add and remove states that managing a handful of one line methods is so onerous?

Comment: Moreover, if these states are really meaningful to your application, wouldn't they require that you change the state-management logic with the addition of each new state? Which means, you would have to re-deploy your application anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone pointed out in the comments, you should make the list of states static rather than dynamic based on a database table.

If you do decide to make this list static, you do the following to avoid having to write a new method every time you add a state.

**app\models\devise.rb**

```
class Devise < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  extend EnumFieldUtil
  enum_field :devise_state, %w[active offline online]
  ...
end
```

Using a utility method that you can define in `lib` folder so that you can re-use it in other models if neccesary

**lib\enum_field_util.rb**

```
module EnumFieldUtil
  def enum_field(field, allowed_values)
    allowed_values.each do |value|
      class_eval %Q{
        define_method("is_#{value}?") { self.#{field} == '#{value}' }
      }
    end

    class_eval %Q{
      validates_inclusion_of :#{field}, :in => #{allowed_values}, :message => "{{value}} must be in #{allowed_values.join ','}"
    }
  end
end
```

Inspired by [Ryan Bate's Rail Casts on state machines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines)